# Iteratre through rows, update and send email

Tags: php, mysql, email, loops, for-loop

I am having an issue with iterating through rows, updating a field, then sending an email depending on the date.  I can get the first row to send an email too but I can't figure out why I cannot get the other rows to send an email to.  I can show that there are three rows returned yet I cannot send three emails.  The code is as follows and thank you in advance for your help.

```
<?php




    for($numOfRows = 1; $numOfRows > 0;){       

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM service WHERE boosterDate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY";

if(!$result = $con->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');  
    }

    $numOfRows = $result->num_rows;
    //%result->store_result();
    $numOfRows = var_dump($numOfRows);
    //echo $numOfRows;

//if($numOfRows > 0){

    //var_dump($numOfRows);

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        //Get all the rows and store them in an array   
    $firstQueryRows[] = $row;

}

foreach($firstQueryRows as $row){

    //do a new query with $row
    $serviceID = $row['serviceID'];
    $patientID = $row['patientID'];
    $serviceName = $row['serviceName'];
    $price = $row['price'];
    $quantity = $row['quantity'];
    $boosterDate = $row['boosterDate'];
    $totalPrice = $row['totalPrice'];
    $rabiesTagNumber = $row['rabiesTagNumber'];
    $microChipNumber = $row['microChipNumber'];
    $rabiesDose = $row['rabiesDose'];
    $rabiesVacType = $row['rabiesVacType'];

    $rabiesVacExpDate = $row['rabiesVacExpDate'];
    $rabiesSerialNumber = $row['rabiesSerialNumber'];
    $rabiesManufacturer = $row['rabiesManufacturer'];
    $rabiesVacDate = $row['rabiesVacDate'];
    $rabiesVacDueBy = $row['rabiesVacDueBy'];
    $licenseNumber = $row['licenseNumber'];
    $isThisARabiesCert = $row['isThisARabiesCert'];
    $vacDate = $row['vacDate'];
    $email30 = $row['email30'];
    $email60 = $row['email60'];
    $email90 = $row['email90'];     
    //echo $serviceID . "  ";
    $sql = "UPDATE service SET email30 = 30 WHERE serviceID = $serviceID";

    if(!$result = $con->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');  
    }

    }//End Foreach



    //echo $patientID;


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM service WHERE email30 = 30";
    if(!$result = $con->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');  
    }

    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        //Get all the rows and store them in an array   
    $firstQueryRows[] = $row;

    $patientID = $row['patientID'];
    //echo $patientID;

}

    foreach($firstQueryRows as $row){



        $sql = "SELECT * FROM patientInformation WHERE patientID = $patientID";
    if(!$result = $con->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');  
    }       

    }

    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        $firstQueryRows[] = $row;
        $clientID = $row['clientID'];
        $maleFemale = $row['maleFemale'];
        $species = $row['species'];
        $ageYears = $row['ageYears'];
        $ageMonths = $row['ageMonths'];
        $weight = $row['weight'];
        $dogBreed = $row['dogBreed'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $catBreed = $row['catBreed'];
        $colors = $row['colors'];
        $illnessLast30Days = $row['illnessLast30Days'];
        $explainIllness = $row['explainIllness'];


        //echo $clientID;   

    }

    foreach($firstQueryRows as $row){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientInformation WHERE clientID = $clientID";
    if(!$result = $con->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');  
    }

    }

    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

        $firstName = $row['firstName'];
        $lastName = $row['lastName'];
        $address = $row['address'];
        $city = $row['city'];
        $zip = $row['zip'];
        $phone = $row['phone'];
        $cell = $row['cell'];
        $state = $row['state'];
        $email = $row['email'];




    }

    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Just a friendly reminder from the Shot Spot";


    $message = "Greetings " . $firstName . " " .    $lastName . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . "\r\n"  .
        "Thank you for choosing the Shot Spot for all of your animals healthcare needs.  This is a friendly reminder that  
                            " . $name . " is ready for their booster on " . $boosterDate . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . 
                            "Thank you for choosing the Shot Spot";


    $headers = 'From: info@txshotspot.com';

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);



}//end for loop


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not itterating thru your for loop and your code is little bit messy :p .
you wanna send three emails try this :

```
for($numOfRows = 0; $numOfRows <= 3; $numOfRows++)
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I want to send as many emails as there are rows that are found.  There happen to be three in this query so setting the for loop the way you have it setup will not work properly.  Also, I understand it isn't coded the best.  Still new to php coding.  Could you offer some advice on the best way to do what I am looking for.  I have three tables and I'm matching id's to all three tables while also checking for a date of within 30 days of today.  At that point I need to send an email to whichever row matches the search criteria.  I can send one but that's where it ends.

Comment: Yes i can give you some advice :

Comment: Yes i can give you some advice .
can you put the three tables structure so i can see what u talking about ? And since you dont know how many email you ve got to send , a While loop will work perfectly in that case .
I also noticed that :
You should use a prepared statment or change your code as the following on each statment . here is an example :
Old code :
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clientInformation WHERE clientID = $clientID";

New code :
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM clientInformation WHERE clientID = '.$clientID;
Wish you good luck , let me know if that works .